# Why this process is nonergodic?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables, intuition, average

I am studying a tutorial on stochastic processes and there's an example in it which I don't understand anything of it.
First of all there is this criterion for a mean-ergodic random process:

> For a WSS random process to be ergodic in the mean, the variance of
>   the sample mean
>   $$\operatorname{var} (\hat\mu_N)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=-(N-1)}^{N-1}\left(1-\frac{|k|}{N}\right)(r_X[k]-\mu^2)$$
>   must converge to zero as $N\to\infty$.

**1- What is $r_X[k]$ in the formula and how is it computed?**

Then there is the following example:

> Define a random process as $X[n]=A$ where $A=N(0,1)$. The random
>   process is WSS since $$\mu_X[n]=E[X[n]]=E[A]=0=\mu$$
>   $$r_X[k]=E[X[n]X[n+k]]=E[A^2]=1$$ However, it should be clear that sample mean will not converge to $\mu$
>   In addition, it can be shown that var(sample mean)=1
>   Each realization is not representative of the ensemble of realizations.

Assuminig that $A=N(0,1)$ is the standard normal distribution
**2- How is it clear that sample mean does not converge to $\mu$?

3- Why var(sample mean)=1?**

Comment: As I understand it: Your "process" is just drawing a random number in each time step and neglecting everything that happened before. Thus, why should it converge? P(X(n)) does not depend on any smaller value of n.  Secondly the sample mean at a given time/length is simply sampling realisations of N(0,1) hence the standard variation of 1. The time average in one sample however will converge to zero.

Answer (score 2):

1. $r_X[k]$ is auto-correlation of WSS random process $X[k]$ given by
   $$r_X[k]=\frac{E[(X[t]-\mu)(X[t+k]-\mu)]}{\sigma^2}$$
   where $\mu=E[X[t]]$ and $\sigma^2=D(X[t])$ are expectation and variance of random process $X$.
2. In this case, sample mean $\hat{\mu}_N=A$ for all $N$ and the sequence $A,A,\ldots$ almost surely does not converge to $\mu$ (it converges to $\mu$ only when $A=\mu$ but $P\{A=\mu\}=0$).
3. Variance $\mathrm{Var}[\hat{\mu}_N]=\mathrm{Var}[A]=1$ as $A$ is standard normal random variable.